# Pandas - How can we apply multiple requirements in a single line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("abc.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet1")
df[['b','c']] = df[['b','c']].apply(lambda x: x*100)
df[['b','c']] = df[['b','c']].apply(lambda x: round(x, 1))
df[['b','c']] = df[['b','c']].astype(str) + '%'
```

I am getting the desired result as this:

```
     a               b               c
0   Savings         0.8%            4.5%
1   Interest rate   50.5%           65.0%
2   Current         1.9%            4.0%
3   Other           4.3%            5.5%
```

but I was just wondering if I can have the last 3 lines in a single line without mentioning the column names again and again.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to call `df.apply` in that case, use reassignment with single expression:

```
df[['b', 'c']] = df[['b', 'c']].mul(100).round(1).astype(str) + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  I just don't think you thought about this hard enough.  ;)

```
df[['b','c']] = df[['b','c']].apply( lambda x: str(round(x*100,1))+'%' )
```

Comment: this will throw the error `TypeError: str() argument 'encoding' must be str, not int`